Question about Lemma 19.1 in Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds
In Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds, page 162 Lemma 19.1 Step 2 it states: Third, we check the local finiteness condition. Let $\mathbf{x}$ be a point of $A$. The point $\mathbf{y}=g(\mathbf{x})$ has a neighborhood $W$ that intersects $T_{i}$ for only finitely many values of $i$. (Here, $T_{i}=support\phi_{i}$.) Then the set $g^{-1}(W)$ is an open set aoubt $\mathbf{x}$ that intersects $S_{i}$ for at most these same values of $i$. (Here, $S_{i}=support\phi_{i}\circ g$)
How to rigorously prove $g^{-1}(W)$ intersects $S_{i}$ for at most these same values of $i$?
This a question from Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds. I show you the whole context of the question below. I have trouble understanding the statement with the red line.


We should have more context please! What’s the whole theorem you’re trying to prove? Local finiteness of what? Etc

@FShrike I want to prove the last sentence of first paragraph in page 162, “we show that the collection ${\phi_i \circ g}$ is a partition of unity on $A$, having compact supports”. To prove ${\phi_i \circ g}$ is a partition of unity on $A$, we need to check “the local finiteness condition” is satisfied. But I have trouble in understanding “the local finiteness condition” is satisfied.

If $\xi\in g^{-1}(W)\cap S_i$, then since $S_i\subset g^{-1}(T_i)$ ( just a few lines above), you must have $g(\xi)\in T_i$. But $\xi$ is also in $g^{-1}(W)$, which means that $g(\xi)\in W$. Hence $g(\xi)\in W\cap T_i$.
Therefore, if $g^{-1}(W)\cap S_i$ for some value $i$, then for the same value of $i$, $W$ intersects $T_i$.

Why does your answer prove “$g^{-1}(W)$ intersects $S_{i}$ for at most these same values of $i$” (which means for other $j$, $g^{-1}(W)\cap S_{j}=\emptyset)$? Notice that the key word is “at most”.

because some of the intersections may be empty. Study harder.

Thank you. It is a great answer! I can understand now.
